# Scale down / up every html element when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I would like to keep the same layout instead of responsive, but scale up / down everything when I resize the window screen.

The font / image may be very small when the screen size is small but that does not matter. The base width is 1920px:

And the site I am working on is:

```
kotechweb.com/new_focus/page/about_us
```

I have attempted in the header.php

```
<meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.1; maximum-scale=2.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

And Jquery

```
$(window).resize(function () {
                    var width = $(window).innerWidth() / 1920;
                    $("#meta").attr("content", "width=device-width; initial-scale=" + width + "; maximum-scale = 1.0; user - scalable = 0; ");
                });
```

But it seems no effect for the desktop browser , thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add css to your body

```
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);
```

For your seconde question :

you said your base width is "1920" so 1920 is the 100%
So what you have to do is

```
calculateNewScale(); // if the user go to the page and his window is less than 1920px
$(window).resize(function () 
{
    calculateNewScale();
});

function calculateNewScale()
{
    var percentageOn1 = $(window).width() / 1920) ;
    $("body").css(
    {
        "-moz-transform": "scale("+percentageOn1 +")",
        "-webkit-transform": "scale("+percentageOn1 +")",
        "transform": "scale("+percentageOn1 +")
    });
}
```

test it and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for reply! it scale everything correctly but I wonder how can it work with the jquery ? for example , how to define the scale number and how to fit the height and width of the screen?